# how to reuse the render result for second scene?

Tags: scene, viewlayers

Ok, i am pretty unexperienced with multiple scenes/view layers.

I know i could solve my "problem" just with shader nodes - the question is more about a general workflow.

Is is possible to make a view layer/scene and use layer1/scene1 as basis for layer2/scene2? and how can i do that?

e.g. i have a scene with a colored photo. In the compositor i make it b/w. And then i want to keep on working with the render result and use this as an image texture for my cylinder and animate that cylinder (i assume in scene2...?)

[image]

so this is my first scene which just "makes" the image b/w ...but i don't know how to "reuse" now in my same project my render result for scene2.

I want to do this in one file.

Comment: Could you add a diagram or proof of concept of what you're trying to do ? I don't understand if you're talking about the render result or the actual objects in the scene ?

Comment: yes, i mean the render result

Comment: Have you tried plugging the output of the HSV node and the output of your second scene to a mix RGB ? When hitting render the first scene will render, then the second one and they will both be available in the compositor

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAx8m.png ?

Comment: dunno if it can be done, maybe consider instead just rendering scene1, saving to file, using file in scene2?

Comment: @JordanSzubert: this is what i didn't want. I want to save time ;)

Comment: You should mention in your question that you do not want to save a file, which could be an option -> [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/230322/edit) ;-)